# Setting radio button to selected in html5 jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have searched Google and stack overflow to no avail on this question. I am trying to add the selected property to a radio button. This should not be a very hard task, but in fact it is proving to be extremely difficult. What I have tried that does not work:

```
$('#radio_1').attr("checked", true);
$('#radio_1').attr("checked", "checked");
$('#radio_1').prop("checked", true);
$('#radio_1').prop("checked", "checked");
```

I have no idea what else to try, as these are the typical solutions.

The radio button code is as follows:

```
<label class="radio inline"><input type="radio" id="radio_1" name="type" value="first">First Name</label>
```

Comment: Code works: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/JfN9V/1/ -- Using prop -- Are you seeing any errors in your console? Any other jQuery code working?

Comment: Doesn't work for me :/

Comment: Doesn't work in which browser?

Comment: I'm using Chrome as well..this works?

Comment: `.prop("checked", true);` is the proper way to do this. Make sure the javascript is added after the elements, or is wrapped in document ready, and that jQuery is included.

Comment: post the original code

Comment: @tymeJV: Technically your code would work even if the Javascript didn't because you chopped off the trailing label, so the button is part of the label ;) But yes, the code does work. It is pretty clear the OP has something else in his code not working, so this is not a real question without the full picture.

Comment: As it turned out, for some bizzare reason my import of jquery was loading slower than the script was being called.

Comment: @Twisterz it will most likely happen everytime. Put your code in a document.ready statement such as $(document).ready(function () {  code });

Comment: I tried that, but it still didn't work. Unfortunately the jquery include has to be in the footer of the website...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Bootstrap.

I don't know about the build that you have, but in the Bootstrap 3 that I'm currently integrating you have to do something like this:

```
$('#radio_1').prop('checked', true).closest('span').toggleClass('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

A way get rid of it, is perform click by programming

```
$('#radio_1').click();
```